# what is the meaning of restrict in pthread_create

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I am looking at pthread_create manual page.

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread,
          const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr,
          void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *restrict arg);
```

What is the meaning of 'restrict' in this function signature ?. what is the purpose of it?

Comment: Did you check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`restrict` places a requirement on the caller that the pointer arguments to this function cannot alias. That is, pointers must not point to the same object.

While this makes obvious sense for `pthread_create`, it's more important for a function like `memcpy`.

```
void * memcpy(void *restrict s1, const void *restrict s2, size_t n);
```

`memcpy` requires that the input buffers do not overlap. It is usually implemented as a simple forward or backward iterating loop, so if the buffers *do* overlap, it could end up copying data that has already been copied.

Comment: Tell me if my understanding is correct. first argument points to some memory location range say from a to d. So, the other arguments in the same function should not point any location inbetween a to d right ? as we see in memcpy ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The two arguments should not point to the same area, nor should any pointer derived from them.

Comment: Thanks Jay, But when i write my own function, and using 'restrict' keyword, how does that matter ?. Confused.

Comment: It's used by the compiler for optimization. It basically provides a hint for alias analysis.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) pretty much answers your question.

It basically tells the compiler that only this pointer, or a pointer derived from it (pointer + 1) will access what the pointer is pointing to.